# Error al crear un item con sequelize

Tags: mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos, sequelize.js

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error al tratar de crear un item con sequelize:

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO `productos`
> (`id_productos`,`idcolor`,`producto`,`idmarca`,`precio`,`descripcion`,`idtalle`,`idcategoria_producto`,`cantidad_stock`)
> VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); (node:14492)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
> at Query.run (C:\Users\DAMIAN\Desktop\Node\Luna\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:46:25)
> at C:\Users\DAMIAN\Desktop\Node\Luna\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:626:28
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async MySQLQueryInterface.insert (C:\Users\DAMIAN\Desktop\Node\Luna\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:749:21)

Entiendo que el error es porque no agregue un catch en el controlador, pero lo que quisiera saber es por que esta fallando, si hay algo mal configurado en las asociaciones o en el controlador.

Este es el controlador:

```
create: (req, res) => {

    db.Producto.create({
        producto: req.body.name_product,
        idcategoria_producto: req.body.category_product,
        idcolor: req.body.color_product,
        idmarca: req.body.brand_product,
        precio: req.body.price_product,
        descripcion: req.body.descript_product,
        idtalle: req.body.size_product,
        cantidad_stock: req.body.quantity_product
    })
    
    res.redirect("/")
}
```

Esta es la asociación del producto que estoy tratando de crear:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Producto";
    
    let cols = {
        id_productos: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        idcolor: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        producto: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(45)
        },
        idmarca: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        precio: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(255)
        },
        idtalle: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        idcategoria_producto: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        cantidad_stock: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "productos",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Producto = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Producto.associate = function(models){

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Marca, {
            as: "marca",
            foreignKey:"idmarca"
        })

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Color, {
            as: "color",
            foreignKey:"idcolor"
        })

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Categoria, {
            as: "categoria",
            foreignKey:"idcategoria_producto"
        })

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Talle, {
            as: "talles",
            foreignKey:"idtalle"
        })

        Producto.hasMany(models.Carrito, {
            as: "producto-carrito",
            foreignKey: "idproducto"
        })

        Producto.hasMany(models.Facturas, {
            as: "producto-facturas",
            foreignKey: "id_producto_facturas"
        })}

    return Producto
}
```

Y las asociaciones de las claves foraneas:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Talle";
    let cols = {
        id_talles: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        talles: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(10)
        },
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "talles",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Talle = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Talle.associate = function(models){
        Talle.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-talle",
            foreignKey: "idtalle"
        })}
        
    return Talle
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Categoria";
    let cols = {
        id_categoria_producto: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        categoria_producto: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(20)
        },
        temporada: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(20)
        }
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "categoria_producto",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Categoria = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Categoria.associate = function(models){
        Categoria.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-categoria",
            foreignKey: "idcategoria_producto"
        })}
        
    return Categoria
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Color";
    let cols = {
        id_colores: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        nombre_color: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(20)
        }
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "colores_productos",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Color = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Color.associate = function(models){
        Color.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-color",
            foreignKey: "idcolor"
        })}

    return Color
}

----------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Marca";
    let cols = {
        id_marcas: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        marcas: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(30)
        },
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "marcas",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Marca = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Marca.associate = function(models){
        Marca.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-marcas",
            foreignKey: "idmarca"
        })}
        
    return Marca
}
```

Probablemente sea un error obvio, pero no lo encuentro.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Add the catch to `db.Producto.create`, and logs the error to get more details about what is wrong. Then, edit your question and add the details. Ah! This is stackoverflow in spanish, so, translate your question.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si contestas una pregunta en otro idioma, aunque sea en comentarios, promoves a que no la traduzcan, por mas que el error sea obvio...

Comment: @gbianchi es que pensé al inicio que estaba en SO en inglés, y para cuando me di cuenta que estaba en español solo atiné a editar mi comentario para agregar que la tradujera. Anotado para la próxima.

Comment: Muchas  gracias @JaimeMenéndez, al leer la info que viene en el error pude solucionarlo.